# Счетчик обновления страницы с записью в файл

Tags: php

Написал скрипт, который считает, сколько раз пользователь обновил страницу и выводит результат на экран.

Возможно ли реализовать данную задачу ещё проще?

```
<?php

$fileName = "file.txt";

if(file_exists($fileName)) {
    $num = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $num++;

    $file = fopen($fileName, "w");
    fwrite($file, $num);
    fclose($file);
} else {
    $num = 0;
    file_put_contents($fileName, $num);
}

echo "Вы обновили страницу {$num} раз(а).";

?>
```

Comment: Сессия? если речь идёт об одном пользователе

Comment: Если 2 разных пользователя будут обновлять страницу то у вас же будет общий счетчик. так что нельзя сказать, что это именно пользователь обновлял страницу. И может тогда уж в сессии счетчик хранить, а не в файле, как раз по пользователю будет. И кстати у вас может быть проблема с совместным доступом к файлу. запрос 1 читает $num, в это время другой процесс обновляет файл, но первый этого не знает и переписывает не измененное число. возможно стоит задуматься о блокировках файла

Comment: Страницу обновляет только один пользователь. 

Данную задачу уже реализовывал на куках и сессиях. Сейчас решил попробовать записывать результат в файл и вот хотел, чтобы опытные программисты проверили код и указали на ошибки :)

Comment: "Страницу обновляет только один пользователь." ???

Comment: ну если только сократить, примерно так - `$num = file_exists($fileName) ? file_get_contents($fileName)++ : 0; file_put_contents($fileName, $num);`

Comment: Есть еще memcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = 'file.txt';
if(file_exists($filename)) $num = file_get_contents($filename);
isset($num) ? $num++ : $num = 0;
echo "Вы обновили страницу ".$num." раз(а).";
file_put_contents($filename, $num);
```